# Auto Height in combination with MaxHeight

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am facing a problem with setting the following xaml layout:

RowHeightAuto.xaml

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="GridMaxHeight.RowHeightAuto"
    Title="RowHeightAuto" WindowState="Maximized">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MaxHeight="200" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Background="LightGray" Grid.Row="0"></StackPanel>
    <DataGrid Name="DataGrid1" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

The DataGrid1 control isn't showing any scrollbars with a lot of columns and rows defined.
Everything works find when I would replace the Height="Auto" with Height="*" than Horizontal and Vertical scrollbars appear like expected.

Also it works when I would declare the MaxHeight directly at the DataGrid1, but that's not really want I want.

Is this a bug that the childcontrol ignores the maxheight on setting Height="Auto" or am I propably making something wrong? Same behaviour can be reproduced with ListBox/ListView and so on, also with third party controls like ComponentOne, Telerik...

If it's a bug - do you know a workaround or have other hints for me?

Here is the code how I set the ItemsSource of the DataGrid.
RowHeightAuto.xaml.cs

```
public partial class RowHeightAuto : Window
{
    private readonly DateTime _start;

    public RowHeightAuto()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataGrid1.ItemsSource = GetTestData();

        _start = DateTime.Now;
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => MessageBox.Show((DateTime.Now - _start).TotalSeconds.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))), DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle, null);
    }

    public static List<TestData> GetTestData()
    {
        const int maxCols = 501;
        const int maxRows = 300;

        var testDatas = new List<TestData>(maxRows);
        for (int i = 0; i < maxRows; i++)
            testDatas.Add(new TestData());

        for (int i = 0; i < maxCols; i++)
        {
            string propName = string.Format("Property{0}", AddLeadingZeros(i));

            for (int j = 0; j < maxRows; j++)
                testDatas[j][propName] = propName;
        }

        return testDatas;
    }

    private static string AddLeadingZeros(int val)
    {
        return val.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).PadLeft(3, '0');
    }
}

public class TestData
{
    public object this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            var myType = GetType();
            var myPropInfo = myType.GetProperty(propertyName);
            return myPropInfo.GetValue(this);
        }
        set
        {
            var myType = GetType();
            var myPropInfo = myType.GetProperty(propertyName);
            myPropInfo.SetValue(this, value, null);

        }
    }

    public string Property000 { get; set; }
    public string Property001 { get; set; }
    public string Property002 { get; set; }
    public string Property003 { get; set; }
    ...
    public string Property498 { get; set; }
    public string Property499 { get; set; }
    public string Property500 { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: +1 for a decently formatted and documented first question. Welcome to SO :)

Comment: And please not that you could write `string.Format("Property{0:000}", i)` instead of calling your `AddLeadingZeros` method.

Comment: @ Viv: Thanks. :)

@ Clemens: Thanks for the input. I am a noob with string formats. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is exactly as you say it is.

The reason why you do not see the `Scrollbar`'s is because even though the `Grid` Clip's the `DataGrid`, it's merely a Clip, the `ActualHeight` of the `DataGrid` is the height it would get if allowed to show all it's children. You are thus not seeing it's scrollbar's. `ActualHeight` is so cos it's allowed to get all the space it wants with `Height="Auto"` on the `Grid`. <strike>The reason I wouldn't call this a bug personally is cos you might desire this behavior if you want to play with the `ClipToBounds` property of the `Grid` for certain animations and this is the behavior you desire.</strike> Thinking about this, I actually think I'd call this a bug too in terms of "Not desirable functionality" than "Incorrect output"

To get the behavior your looking for,

- Apply the `MaxHeight` on the `DataGrid` or use Grid `RowDefinition.Height="*"` <- both as you mentioned (Not sure why you say this is not what you want to do?)
- Or you could also use a `RelativeSourceBinding` on the `DataGrid`

something like -

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGrid1" 
          Grid.Row="1"
          Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                           AncestorType={x:Type Grid}},
                           Path=RowDefinitions[1].ActualHeight}">
```

For such issues **[Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)** is your friend. You can easily check this behavior and realize why the scrollbar's aren't shown when you check the `ActualHeight` on your `DataGrid` using Snoop and see it allocates quite a bit more height to the child control.

Comment: Dont really understand why this is happening, in my layout I am clearing stating I only want a MaxHeight of 200.
Can you maybe explain a little more why someone would want a fully size child element when stating the MaxHeight?

And maybe a reason why even the Horizontal Srollbar isnt getting displayed, which absolutly makes no sense to me.

Comment: @RandRandom But you're also saying `Height="Auto"` which translates to "take all the space you want". This is just my opinion btw. You could raise it on MSDN as a bug and ask them why specifying Auto does not force the child control to respect the `MaxHeight` on the `Grid.RowDefinition`. To me say if you specify "*" as Height, then the child is allowed to take "any available space from the parent" which happens to get limited by MaxHeight and thus the output is what you expect.

Comment: @RandRandom ..contd. However when you set `Height="Auto"` there's a mismatch where the Grid's row on one hand is forced to only take 200 in ActualHeight by MaxHeight while the child is allowed to take as much as it needs via the Auto for Height and it happens both satisfy the requirements given by letting the child take the space it needs when the Grid's row itself conforms to the max 200 it was given.

Comment: @RandRandom As for the horizontal scroll-bar, it has nothing to do with this issue but is an innocent victim of side-effects. The horizontal-scrollbar is outside the 200 size in height and you thus do not see it. but it's always there at the bottom end of the `DataGrid`