# How to make scrollviewer work with Height set to Auto in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, uwp-xaml, scrollviewer, autosize

I have learned that if the height of a grid row, where the `ScrollViewer` resides, is set as `Auto`, the vertical scroll bar will not take effect since the actual size of the `ScrollViewer` can be larger than the height in sight. So in order to make the scroll bar work, I should set the height to either a fixed number or star height

However, I now have this requirement, that I have two different views reside in two grid rows, and I have a toggle button to switch between these two views: when one view is shown, the other one is hidden/disappeared. So I have defined two rows, both heights are set as `Auto`. And I bind the visibility of the view in each row to a boolean property from my ViewModel (one is converted from `True` to `Visible` and the other from `True` to `Collapsed`. The idea is when one view's visibility is `Collapsed`, the height of the grid row/view will be changed to 0 automatically.

The view show/hidden is working fine. However, in one view I have a `ScrollViewer`, which as I mentioned doesn't work when the row height is set as `Auto`. Can anybody tell me how I can fulfill such requirement while still having the `ScrollViewer` working automatically`? I guess I can set the height in code-behind. But since I am using MVVM, it would require extra communication/notification. Is there a more straightforward way to do that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Change Height from `Auto` to `*`, if you can.

Example:

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="525">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  Background="LightGray">

        <Grid Width="100">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" x:Name="_scroll1">
                <Border Height="300" Background="Red" />
            </ScrollViewer>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=_scroll1, Path=ActualHeight}" Grid.Row="1"/>
        </Grid>

        <Grid Width="100">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" x:Name="_scroll2">
                    <Border Height="300" Background="Green" />
                </ScrollViewer>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=_scroll2, Path=ActualHeight}" Grid.Row="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I don't quite understand your answer. Firstly, you are trying to make the comparison by making two Grid, each has two rows, and one Grid has a row height set as Auto and the other Grid set one row height as *. Is it correct? But if I set the row height of the ScrollViewer as *, would it always take all the available space, even when I want to hide it totally? I also posted my XAML code in the update.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong about my first comments. Making both row height as * indeed make show/hide when I set the visibility of one row as visible and the other as Collapsed

Answer (score 32):

In MVVM, the way that worked for me was to bind the height of the `ScrollViewer` to the `ActualHeight` of the parent control (which is always of type `UIElement`).

`ActualHeight` is a read-only property which is only set after the control has been drawn onto the screen. It may change if the window is resized.

```
<StackPanel>
    <ScrollViewer Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, 
           RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UIElement}}">
        <TextBlock Text=Hello"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</StackPanel>
```

### But what if the parent control has an infinite height?

If the parent control has an infinite height, then we have a bigger problem. We have to keep setting the height of all parents, until we hit a control with a non-infinite height.

[Snoop](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf) is absolutely invaluable for this:

[image]

If the "Height" for any XAML element is `0` or `NaN`, you can set it to something using one of:

- `Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UIElement}}"`
- `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"`
- `Height="Auto"`

Hint: Use `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` if you are a child of a `Grid` with a `<RowDefinition Height="*">`, and the `Binding RelativeSource...` elsewhere if that doesn't work.

---

If you're interested, here is all of my previous attempts to fix this issue:

### Appendix A: Previous Attempt 1

Can also use this:

```
Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=StackPanel}}"
```

### Appendix B: Previous Attempt 2

Useful info: see [Auto Height in combination with MaxHeight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742513/wpf-auto-height-in-combination-with-maxheight).

If nothing seems to work, it's probably because the `ActualHeight` of the parent is either 0 (so nothing is visible) or huge (so the scrollviewer never needs to appear). This is more of a problem if there are deeply nested grids, with a scrollviewer right at the bottom.

- Use Snoop to find the `ActualHeight` of the parent `StackPanel`. In properties, filter by the word `"Actual"`, which brings back `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth`.
- If `ActualHeight` is zero, give it a minimum height using `MinHeight`, so we can at least see something.
- If `ActualHeight` is so huge that it goes off the edge of the screen (i.e. 16,000), give it a reasonable maximum height using `MaxHeight`, so the scrollbars will appear.

Once the scrollbars are appearing, then we can clean it up further:

- Bind the `Height` of the `StackPanel` or `Grid` to the `ActualHeight` of the parent.

Finally, put a `ScrollViewer` inside this `StackPanel`.

### Appendix C: Previous Attempt 3

It turns out that this can sometimes fail:

```
Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=StackPanel}}"
```

The reason?  It the binding fails, the height will be zero and nothing will be seen. The binding can fail if we are binding to an element which is not accessible. The binding will fail if we are going `up` the visual tree, then `down` to a leaf node (e.g. up to the parent grid, then down to the `ActualHeight` of a row attached to that grid). This is why binding to the `ActualWidth` of a `RowDefinition` simply won't work.

### Appendix D: Previous Attempt 4

I ended up getting this working by making sure that `Height=Auto` for all of the parent elements from us to the first `<Grid>` element in the UserControl.

Comment: Yes! Thanks! This is exactly what I thought of, but didn't know how to do it. +1 also for showing an example of how to bind to a parent control (without using ElementName). The more I learn about WPF, the more awesome it is. Favoriting this question just because of this answer

Comment: But hopefully this works when trying to bind to the Height of his "great great... grandpda element".... Guessing that's what "AncestorLevel" is for... time to google.

Comment: In my case I had a StackPanel wrapped by a ScrollViewer. The ScrollViewer was placed in a grid and for me it worked by binding the ActualHeight of the RowDefinition instead of the Grid's height or defining UIElement as AncestorType:

`Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=RowDefinition}}"`

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar problem, taking me hours to figure out the solution. What solved it was using a Dockpanel as parent container instead of a StackPanel. Just specify all children to dock to top if the functionality should be similar to vertical stackpanel. Consider using LastChildFill="False" in the Dock XAML which is'n default.

So instead of:

```html
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  <Textbox>SomeTextBox</Textbox>
  <Scrollviewer/>
</StackPanel>
```

Try:

```html
<DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
  <Textbox DockPanel.Dock="Top">SomeTextBox</Textbox>
  <Scrollviewer DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either set a fix height on your ScrollViewer but then you have to consider that the second row of your grid will have that height too since row's first child will be the ScrollViewer and row's height is auto, or you bind the height of ScrollViewer to another control in your layout. We don't know how your layout looks alike.

At the end if you don't like neither of both just set the row's height to * as swiszcz suggested or hack wpf write your own custom panel that will be able to layout everything possible in every parallel universe or something like that. :)

Answer (score 0):

What I discover is that you have to put your `ScrollViewer`  within a container that has `Height=Auto` or you get his parent `Heigh Actual Size` and apply it to that container.

In my case I have `UserControl` like

```
  <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Padding="0,2,0,0">
                    <ScrollViewer Height="Auto" ZoomMode="Disabled" IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="True"  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                     HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                     VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"> 
                        <ListView  ItemsSource="{x:Bind PersonalDB.View, Mode=OneWay}" x:Name="DeviceList"
                           ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ContactListViewTemplate}"
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="False"
                    Grid.Row="1" 
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    BorderThickness="0,0,0,0"
                    BorderBrush="DimGray">
                            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <ItemsStackPanel AreStickyGroupHeadersEnabled="False" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                                <GroupStyle>
                                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local1:GroupInfoList">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Key}" 
                                       Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                                </GroupStyle>
                            </ListView.GroupStyle>
                        </ListView>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
```

And I add it dinamically to `ContentControl` which is within a `Page`.

```
 <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="0,0,12,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="70"  /> 
            <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="200"  />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions> 
 <Grid Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"     >
            <ContentControl x:Name="UIControlContainer"  />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Notice that `Heigh` of the `Row` is `*`

When I populate `ContentControl` I use this code in `Loaded` event

```
  UIControlContainer.Content = new UIDeviceSelection() { 
VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch,
HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch,
Height = UIControlContainer.ActualHeight,
Width = UIControlContainer.ActualWidth
};
```

And also when `ContentControl` changes its size you have to update size of the `UserControl`.

```
 UIControlContainer.SizeChanged += UIControlContainer_SizeChanged;

 private void UIControlContainer_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (UIControlContainer.Content != null)
            {
                if (UIControlContainer.Content is UserControl)
                {
                    (UIControlContainer.Content as UserControl).Height = UIControlContainer.ActualHeight;
                    (UIControlContainer.Content as UserControl).Width = UIControlContainer.ActualWidth;
                }
            }
        }
```

Enjoy!

P.S. Acctually I did it for UWP.