# DevExpress.Wpf.Grid.InfiniteGridSizeException was unhandled

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, devexpress

When using DevExpress, I see this error:

> DevExpress.Wpf.Grid.InfiniteGridSizeException was unhandled
>             Message="By default, an infinite grid height is not allowed since all grid rows will be rendered and hence the grid will work very slowly. To fix this issue, you should place the grid into a container that will give a finite height to the grid, or you should manually specify the grid's Height or MaxHeight. Note that you can also avoid this exception by setting the GridControl.AllowInfiniteGridSize static property to True, but in that case the grid will run slowly."

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the `DXGrid` has an infinite height.

To fix, set the height to something non-infinite.

Snoop is absolutely invaluable for this:

[image]

If the "Height" for the XAML element is infinite (i.e. `0` or `NaN`), you can set it using *one* of the following:

- Option 1: `Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UIElement}}"`
- Option 2: `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"`
- Option 3: `Height="Auto"`

Hint: Use `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` if you are a child of a `Grid` with a `<RowDefinition Height="*">`, and the `Binding RelativeSource...` elsewhere if that doesn't work.

#### But what if the parent control has an infinite height?

If the parent control has an infinite height, then we have a bigger problem. We have to keep setting the height of each successive parent, until we hit a control with a non-infinite `ActualHeight`.

#### Appendix A: Related Posts

- [How to make scrollviewer work with Height set to Auto in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355818/how-to-make-scrollviewer-work-with-height-set-to-auto-in-wpf/25663419#25663419)
- [DevExpress: InfiniteGridSizeException was unhandled](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q431369).
- [DevExpress: Grid throws InfiniteGridSizeException when in stackpanel](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B190315).

Comment: none of these doesn't work for me, I have my grid in an exapander in an ItemControl

Comment: What is the ActualHeight of the control? If it is infinite, look at ActualHeight of the parent, and repeat until you find a parent with a finite height. Then work your way down, setting the height of all controls until you hit your one.

Answer (score 4):

It is a possible case when your grid has *no* parent with the finite height. For example, as a **ScrollViewer** content.

To fix that, you can set static property **GridControl.AllowInfiniteGridSize** to **true**, but **GridControl** will not use the virtualization mechanism in that case.

So, the better option here is to set **MaxHeight** for it.
But since grids are usually very dynamic at the size, simple constant for **MaxHeight** wouldn't be the best.
You may want to calculate actual max height for your grid. **DXBinding** might be helpful here:

```
<dxg:GridControl
     MaxHeight="{DXBinding '@s.VisibleRowCount * $const:GridHelper.RowMaxHeight'}" />
```

where **RowMaxHeight** is your constant that is also used for cell templates

Answer (score 3):

To add to this, I recently had the same issue and I ended up binding MaxHeight to the screen height. Might not apply in all scenario's, but it's a quick fix for most.

```xml
<dxg:GridControl MaxHeight="{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}" />
```