# Put the item below listbox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I don't know how to put element below listbox. Listbox should occupy the whole screen.

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox>
        <ListBoxItem>//Elements from ViewModel</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
    <TextBlock>Additional elment</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

But scroll doesn't works. I can not assign a high, because it is unknown

I would have the following result: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for example use a DockPanel:

```
<DockPanel>
    <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">Additional element</TextBlock>
    <ListBox>
        <ListBoxItem>//Elements from ViewModel</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
</DockPanel>
```

The last element in the DockPanel, i.e. the ListBox in this case, will fill the remaining space unless you set the LastChildFill property of the DockPanel to false: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dockpanel.lastchildfill(v=vs.110).aspx

StackPanels don't work very well with scrollbars. Please refer to my answer to the below question for more information about this.

[Horizontal scroll for stackpanel doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140287/horizontal-scroll-for-stackpanel-doesnt-work)

> Your solution will make additional element be will at the bottom of the window, not below the last item in the listbox. My problem is different.

Use a Grid then:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListBox Grid.Row="0" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1">Additional element</TextBlock>
    <!--  Grid.Row="2" = the rest of the window content... -->
</Grid>
```

> i want the additional element to scroll with the rest - it is a button

Use a CompositeCollection as the ItemsSource for the ListBox then instead of binding directly to your source property:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="itemsSource" Source="{Binding YourViewModelSourceCollection}" />
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsSource}}" />
            <TextBlock>Additional element</TextBlock>
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ListBox.ItemsSource>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Your solution will make additional element be will at the bottom of the window, not below the last item in the listbox. My problem is different.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to put the additional element *inside* the ListBox? Then you should add another object to the ListBox itself. If you want to put the element below the ListBox you could also use a Grid. I edited my answer.

Comment: I don't want to have the additional element on the list - but I want an additional element behaved in this way.

Your solution with grid will make that any scrolls will not be visible.

Comment: Do you want the additional element to scroll with the rest of the items in the ListBox or what?

Comment: Yes, i want the additional element to scroll with the rest - it is a button :/

Comment: Use a CompositeCollection as the ItemsSource for the ListBox instead of binding directly to your source property then. I edited my answer again.