# WPF ItemsControl display only first item

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, itemscontrol

I have ItemsControl defined in XAML.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    ...

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2" Margin="5" MaxHeight="160">

        <ItemsControl Name="FilterItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Filters}" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <GroupBox Header="{Binding Path=Key}" Margin="10,0,0,5" MaxWidth="150">
                        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Value}" >
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox  Content="{Binding Path=Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked}" Margin="1"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </GroupBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>

    </StackPanel>

    ...

</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
public Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<CheckableItem>> Filters
    {
        get 
        { 
            return filters; 
        }
        set
        {
            filters = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Filters");
        }
    }
```

And simple class for CheckableItem:

```
public class CheckableItem
{
    private long id;
    private bool isChecked;
    private string name;

    public long Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return isChecked; }
        set { isChecked = value; }
    }
}
```

Filters dictionary is properly filled in ViewModel. Also Filters.Count is greater than one. 
I want to display every KeyValuePair from dictionary in horizontal orientation but only first item from the dictionary is shown, why?

Also, is code for horizontal orientation ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting a `ScrollViewer` inside a `StackPanel` is a bad idea as a `StackPanel` measures its children with an infinite space:

[Horizontal scroll for stackpanel doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140287/horizontal-scroll-for-stackpanel-doesnt-work)

If you want the `ItemsControl` to layout the items horizontally you should set its `ItemsPanel` to a horizontal `StackPanel`.

Try this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" Margin="5" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl Name="FilterItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Filters}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <GroupBox Header="{Binding Path=Key}" Margin="10,0,0,5" MaxWidth="150">
                        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Value}" >
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox  Content="{Binding Path=Name}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked}" Margin="1"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </GroupBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```