# Xaml - Vertical scrollbar in stackpanel

Tags: wpf, xaml, vertical-scrolling

I have creating a wpf application and in my settings panel I have tons of UI elements. The problem is that when I resize the window some of these elements are not visible anymore. Is there any way to add a simple vertical scrollbar?

I have tried this below and add my content into it :

```
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
       <Grid>
          <StackPanel>
              //Content
          </StackPanel>
       </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

I'm not sure if I put the ScrollViewer to the right Place but I got this error :

> The member resources is not recognized or is not accessible

and for this error I have tried to replace the `Page.Resources` with `Window.Resources` but it did not help.

Anyways how could I get my vertical scrollbar working? Any helps?

Comment: Can you provide details on how you "added" your controls? And I'm not sure if the error you mentioned is related to the `ScrollViewer` itself. Maybe show more code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved by removing the `Width` and `Height` properties from the Page.

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      Height="800" Width="1400"
      WindowTitle="ScrollViewer Sample">
  <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
     <Grid>
       <StackPanel>
          //Content
       </StackPanel>
     </Grid>
  </ScrollViewer>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should get rid of the `StackPanel`. A `StackPanel` measures its children with an infinite space and therefore it doesn't work very well with scroll bars:

[Horizontal scroll for stackpanel doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140287/horizontal-scroll-for-stackpanel-doesnt-work/41140885#41140885)

Comment: What would you use instead?