# How to set height to the dynamically added user control in stackpanel?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

**We are having wpf user control (UserControl.xaml) in one dll (Child.dll).**

**We added the reference of "Child.dll" in to another application (ParentApplication)**

**In parent application we have one stackpanel in which we have to add the user control dynamically using the user control constructor.**

ParentApplication contains :

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:fa="http://schemas.fontawesome.io/icons/" x:Class="ParentApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns:Mvis="clr-namespace:Mvis;assembly=Mvis"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="1000" Width="1000" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized">
<Grid>
        <TabControl>
<TabItem Cursor="Hand">
                <TabItem.Header>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="ChildApplication"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </TabItem.Header>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanContentScroll="True" Grid.Row="0" >
                        <StackPanel x:Name="userControlPlaceHolder" Background="Blue"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

So we doing it like this on **MainWindow.xaml.cs** :

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            UserControl userControl = new UserControl();
            this.userControlPlaceHolder.Children.Add(userControl);           
        }
}
```

**Issue 1: User control is displayed only in half height of the screen.**

**Note: We did not set any height to UserControl.xaml and we can not set the height control height like userControl.Height=200; **

**Issue 2: We have used scroll viewer in MainWindow.xaml, but when we resize the application window, vertical scroll bar is not displayed.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `StackPanel` and add the `UserControl` directly to the `ScrollViewer`:

```
<TabItem Cursor="Hand">
    <TabItem.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="ChildApplication"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </TabItem.Header>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="sv" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanContentScroll="True" Grid.Row="0" >

        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

---

```
this.sv.Content = userControl;
```

`ScrollViewers` and `StackPanels` don't work well together:

[Horizontal scroll for stackpanel doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140287/horizontal-scroll-for-stackpanel-doesnt-work/41140885#41140885)