# status bar disappears after populating datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, statusbar, hidden, status

I have user controls that contains datagrid.
My status bar disappears as soon as grid populates even though I have enough margins and there's empty space at the bottom.  What am i doing wrong????

```
<DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" LastChildFill="False">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0">


        <controls:ucXXXXSummary  x:Name="ucSummary"  Margin="20,20,20,30" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>

     <controls:XXXXUC x:Name="ucXXXX"  Margin="20,20,20,30" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"/>
    </StackPanel>


    <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Height="25">
        <StatusBarItem>
            <StatusBarItem>
                <TextBlock Name="lblStatus" Text="abc!!!!!!!!!!!"/>
            </StatusBarItem>
        </StatusBarItem>
    </StatusBar>

</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't rely on margins to position elements relative to each other. Use an appropriate `Panel` such as for example a `Grid`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <controls:ucXXXXSummary  x:Name="ucSummary" Margin="20,20,20,30" />
    <controls:XXXXUC Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ucXXXX"  Margin="20,20,20,30" />
    <StatusBar Grid.Row="2" Height="25">
        <StatusBarItem>
            <StatusBarItem>
                <TextBlock Name="lblStatus" Text="abc!!!!!!!!!!!"/>
            </StatusBarItem>
        </StatusBarItem>
    </StatusBar>
</Grid>
```

`StackPanels` don't play well with scrollable content: [Horizontal scroll for stackpanel doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140287/horizontal-scroll-for-stackpanel-doesnt-work/41140885#41140885)