# WPF - First datagrid of two, max height

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, user-controls

I am trying to create a UserControl that can be use like a frozingDatagrid for row (cause there is no one by default). My UserControl is basic :

```
<UserControl ..>
   <Grid>
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>

       <Datagrid Name="Frozen" Grid.Row="0" MaxHeight="{Binding Height, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" ... />
       <Datagrid Name="Normal" Grid.Row="1" ... />
   </Grid>
```

I want the scroll option only for the Normal datagrid, except if the Frozen datagrid height exceed the height of the user control. For now the Frozen datagrid his expend for all items he contains.

EDIT :

I am able to get the result you have with your example.

But when i resize my window smaller if the frozen part become cut and no scroll bar appear. I thought that put MaxHeight property would be good, but its like the style apply before the control is generate on screen so UserControl doesn't have a heigth. So its set MaxHeight to NaN and my datagrid is longer then my control so I miss data.

Thanks

Comment: Sory would like to add image to help, but i dont have enought rep.... =(

Comment: You can still upload your image to some image host, and add a link in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are after something like this (But with `DataGrids` instead of simple `TextBlocks` - I currenty only have access to [Kaxaml](http://www.kaxaml.com/), but the basic idea is the same):

[image: frozen vs normal]

Here is the XAML for that (without the full lorem ipsum part):

```
<Grid x:Name="grid" Height="400" Width="350">
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
           <RowDefinition x:Name="normalRow" Height="*"/>
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>

       <TextBlock x:Name="Frozen" Grid.Row="0" 
                  MaxHeight="{Binding Path=Height, ElementName=grid}" 
                  Background="LightBlue" TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="5">
           Lorem ipsum dolor...
       </TextBlock>

       <ScrollViewer x:Name="Normal" Grid.Row="1" 
                     MaxHeight="{Binding Path=Height, ElementName=normalRow}" >
           <TextBlock Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap">
               Lorem ipsum dolor...
           </TextBlock>
       </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

The main idea is to name the `RowDefinition`, and bind the "Normal" part's `Height` to it's `Height` property, while binding the first row's `MaxHeight` to the `Height` of the `Grid`.

A common "trick" I often use: name your `UserControl` (e.g.: `x:Name="Instance"`), that way you can easily bind to it's properties, in this case the `Width` and `Height` of the outermost `Grid` control.

---

**Update:**

The problem that the content of the first row gets cut if you size the control to a small enough size could be fixed by introducing a `MaxHeight` to that `RowDefinition`, and binding it to the `Height` of the `Grid` itself, but unfortunately it seems that setting a `RowDefinition`'s `Heigth` to `Auto` causes it to disregard any `MaxHeight` setting (see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17742513/1552016))...

But here is a workaround:

```
<UserControl x:Name="instance">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition x:Name="normalRow" Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ScrollViewer x:Name="Frozen" Grid.Row="0" 
                     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                     MaxHeight="{Binding ElementName=instance, Path=Height}">
            <TextBlock x:Name="test" Background="LightBlue" TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="5" >
               Lorem ipsum dolor ...
            </TextBlock>
        </ScrollViewer>

        <ScrollViewer x:Name="Normal" Grid.Row="1" 
                     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                     MaxHeight="{Binding Path=Height, ElementName=normalRow}" >
            <TextBlock Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap">
               Lorem ipsum dolor ...
            </TextBlock>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The trick is to bind the first column's content's `MaxHeight` to the Height of the `UserControl`.

Of course in your case the `ScrollViewers` are not really needed as the `DataGrid` has built-in scrollbars, but I hope you get the idea.